# How to execute a jQuery script if an element has a certain font?

Tags: jquery, css, fonts

I'm working on a new website and I've run into this issue.

My navbar on the website works fine as long as the default font (BebasNeueRegular) is used, which it is in Firefox and Chrome. I recently checked the website in IE and found that it doesn't use BebasNeueRegular, so it uses the next font (Helvetica, I believe) and this throws the whole thing out of whack.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8y6r.jpg

The first picture there is how it's supposed to look and the second one is what happens when BebasNeueRegular is not used. The list element in the first example is 62x48 while in the second picture it's 78.65 x 48. This is causing the last two links to be bumped off into the second row, which looks terrible.

What I was *hoping* to do was use jQuery to shrink the font-size if any font other than BebasNeueRegular is used. I have this right now:

```
if($('nav.main > ul > li > a > span').css('font-family') !== 'BebasNeueRegular'){
   alert(Success!);
}
```

But so far, I haven't gotten the "Success!" prompt to indicate that it works.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Can I check for a certain font-family and execute a script based on whether or not it's used? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I guess your font-family attribute is setted correctly. But the browser can't load the font for any reason. So probably jQuery won't do it.

Comment: Is there any workaround that you know of? As long as I end up with the Navbar all on one line across all browsers, I'm not picky as to how I get there.

Comment: I'm not very experienced, but imho PHP would do it. Use any function to get the current browser and then change the font properties before serving the page.

Comment: Cool, guess it's time to start learning PHP. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is currently doing the following:

```
//Retrieves all Elements that match the selector
$('nav.main > ul > li > a > span')

//Returns the 'font-family' style for the first element in the set
.css('font-family')
```

You want to check *every* element instead of just the first one. You can accomplish this using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('nav.main > ul > li > a > span').each(function(index, el) {
    //If not BebasNeueRegular...
    if ($(el).css('font-family') !== 'BebasNeueRegular') {
        //Lower the font size
        $(el).css('font-size', '10px');
    }
});
```

A fiddle example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/m94u80bm/1/

A similar example that uses [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead is here: http://jsfiddle.net/m94u80bm/2/

Comment: Thank you so much! I gotta read up on my jQuery, there's always some cool selectors that I forget. Quick question though, what is the (index, el) doing within that function?

Comment: @CaptainKick The `(index, el)` are the parameters of the function. In the documentation of [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), it is specified that the index and element are passed to the function. In this case `el` is the current DOM element, and `index` is it's index in the selection. (Note: inside the function `el` == `this`).